# php preg_match_all() not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

In the example string below I have 5 times **#A#** and 11 times **#B#**   but preg_match_all returns only one match for **#A#** and 0 matches for **#B#**. Any idea how to solve this ?

```
$string = '<div>#Α#</div><div i="">#Α#</div><div i=""><a href="#Β#" class="" s="" p="65" t="4"></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s="" p="65" t="4"></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s="" p="68" t="4"></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s=""></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s="" p="75" t="2"></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s=""></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s="" p="65" t="3"></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s="" p="60" t="4"></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s=""></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s="" p="60" t="4"></a><a href="#Β#" class="" s="sv_plus" p="75" t="3"></a><noscript><center><h1 style="color:red;font-size:50px">#A#</h1></center><div>#Α#</div></noscript><div>#Α#</div>';

preg_match_all("/\#A\#/",$string,$matches);
print_r($matches); //return only one match instead 5

preg_match_all("/\#B\#/",$string,$matches);
print_r($matches); //return zero matches instead 11
```

Comment: Incredible, I haven't any idea why!!!

Comment: Not sure the problem yet, but you can use this useful tester to play with it: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/kfs

Comment: Who is the stupid person that downvotes this question? I really don't see any reason.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Probably someone who (rightfully) thinks that parsing HTML with regexps is an awful idea. Not a good reason to downvote a question though, especially since this specific issue is not even related to that fact that there's HTML here.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: You are probably right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your string only contains `#A#` once and doesn't contain `#B#`.

It does contain `#Α#` four times and `#Β#` 11 times though.

The difference is that the second versions contain a [Greek Capital Letter Alpha](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0391/index.htm) and a [Greek Capital Letter Beta](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0392/index.htm), not ascii A and B.

Comment: How did you find that out?

Comment: @DavidFindlay I hit F12 and pasted `#Α#` from his source into my browser's console and then changed it to `'#Α#'.split('').map( x => x.charCodeAt() )`. I've seen similar problems before, so it was my first hunch.

Comment: @MTK As an aside, escaping the `#` with a backslash has no effect